# Using setState for external UI components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am fairly new to react and I am currently using react native. I am trying to create a component that is decoupled from my state management library, be it redux or flux, with the intention that I can eventually share it publicly. My problem stems from the fact that I am currently using redux but the component itself is using `this.state` and `this.setState` to maintain its internal state which seems like an anti-pattern, and the renders don't seem to be working. So my question is, how do I create an isolated component that doesn't rely on redux, flux, etc.. but is able to maintain internal state? How do third party components usually do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using the component's state (`this.state`) is an anti-pattern. In fact, I think that this is the right way for a component to maintain/update its own, internal state. The only thing you need to be aware of is that changing a component's state (using `this.setState`) will trigger the `render()` to be called again. If for you want to update the state but you do **not** want the component to be rendered again, then you should override and properly implement the component's `shoudComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` function.

There are many reasons for a component to update its state. For example, I have a component with a `render()` function similar to this:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.networkError) {
        return <ErrorView />
    } else if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return <Spinner visible={true}/>
    } else {
        return <Text>Success</Text>
    }
}
```

So based on its current state, the component renders the corresponding child component.